# jQuery Validate not binding, with no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a simple form with jQuery Validate and I have initialized the jQuery Validate plugin and setup my rules and messages, but for some reason it's still firing the form submit, and refreshing the page, without validating the form.

I have the same rules setup on another form, and it works. I need it to validate and fire the submit handler, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Included Javascripts**

```
   <script src="/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <!-- jQuery Validate -->
   <script src='/js/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
   <script src='/js/jquery/additional-methods.min.js'></script>
```

**Html**

```
 <ul id="updateEmailFormAlert" class="alert alert-danger">
 </ul> 

  <form id="updateEmailForm" role="form" class="form">
     <div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address"/></div>
     <div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" id="emailConfirm" name="emailConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email Address"/></div>
     <div class="col-md-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm center form-btn">Update Email</button></div>
  </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready() {
   validateUpdateEmailForm();
}
var updateEmailValidator = null;
function validateUpdateEmailForm() {
    updateEmailValidator = $("#updateEmailForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
        wrapper: 'li',
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#emailConfirm").is(":filled");
                    }
                },
                email: true
            },
            emailConfirm: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#email").is(":filled");
                    }
                },
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#email",
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Email is required",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            emailConfirm: {
                required: "Confirm Email is required",
                email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {

            return false;
        }
});
```

**EDIT**

My javascript is correct, here is my complete file, the previous code was an example, forgot to close the ready function...but not in my actual code.

/**
 * Manages users Models and ViewModels in Knockout UI.
 */

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     // setup jquery validate on the update email form
    validateUpdateEmailForm();

    // setup knockout bindings
    ko.applyBindings(new UsersViewModel());

     // highlight the selected nav
    $("#nav-users").addClass('active');   
});

// user model
var User = function(user) {
    var self = this;

    self.id              = ko.observable(user.id);
    self.username        = ko.observable(user.username);
    self.date_created    = ko.observable(user.date_created);
    self.active          = ko.observable(user.active);
    self.last_login      = ko.observable(user.last_login);
    self.role            = ko.observable(user.role);
    self.profile_id      = ko.observable(user.profile_id);
    self.first_name      = ko.observable(user.first_name);
    self.last_name       = ko.observable(user.last_name);
    self.email           = ko.observable(user.email);
    self.avatar          = ko.observable(user.avatar);
    self.on_mailing_list = ko.observable(user.on_mailing_list);
    self.requests        = ko.observable(user.requests);

    self.name = ko.computed(function() {
       return user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
    });

    self.joined = ko.computed(function() {
        return timeSince(new Date(user.date_created));
    });

    self.joinedOn = ko.computed(function() {
        var jsDate = new Date(user.date_created);
        var formattedDate = jsDate.getMonth() + "/" + jsDate.getDate() + "/" + jsDate.getFullYear();
        return formattedDate;
    });

    self.lastLogin = ko.computed(function() {
        var jsDate = new Date(user.last_login);
        var formattedDate = jsDate.getMonth() + "/" + jsDate.getDate() + "/" + jsDate.getFullYear();
        return jsDate.getFullYear() == "1969" ? "Never" : formattedDate;
    });

    self.onMailingList = ko.computed(function() {
        return user.on_mailing_list == 1 ? 'fa-envelope' : '';
    });

    self.status = ko.computed(function() {
        return user.active == 1 ? 'fa-check green-accent' : 'fa-exclamation-circle red-accent';
    });

    self.statusText = ko.computed(function() {
        return user.active == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive";
    });

    self.isSubscriber = ko.computed(function() {
        return user.on_mailing_list == 1 ? "Yes" : "No";
    });

    self.roleTag = ko.computed(function() {
        return user.role == 'member' ? 'member-tag' : 'admin-tag';
    });    

    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function() {
        return false;
    }, this);
}

// users view model
var UsersViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.users        = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedUser = ko.observable();

    // select the first item
    self.selectedUser(self.users()[0]);

    // load initial data
    $.getJSON('/admin/users/getusers', {}, function(users) {
        var mappedUsers = $.map(users, function(user) {
            return new User(user);
        });
        self.users(mappedUsers);

        // select the first restaurant
        $("#ghost-list li:first").trigger('click');
    });


    self.addUser = function() {

    };

    self.removeUser = function() {

    };

    self.filter = function(field, sortOrder) {
        $.getJSON('/admin/users/filter', {field: field, sortOrder: sortOrder}, function(users) {
            var mappedUsers = $.map(users, function(user) {
                return new User(user);
            });
            self.users(mappedUsers);
        })
    };
}

var updateEmailValidator = null;
function validateUpdateEmailForm() {
    updateEmailValidator = $("#updateEmailForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
        wrapper: 'li',
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#emailConfirm").is(":filled");
                    }
                },
                email: true
            },
            emailConfirm: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("#email").is(":filled");
                    }
                },
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#email",
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Email is required",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            emailConfirm: {
                required: "Confirm Email is required",
                email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {

            return false;
        }
    });
}
function validateResetPasswordForm() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so it looks like I just had to create a custom binding in Knockout js to apply the .validate().

```
 // activate the jQuery Validate on the form
 ko.bindingHandlers.validateEmailForm = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {      
        $(element).validate({
            errorLabelContainer: $("#updateEmailFormAlert"),
            wrapper: 'li',
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#emailConfirm").is(":filled");
                        }
                    },
                    email: true
                },
                emailConfirm: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function(element) {
                            return $("#email").is(":filled");
                        }
                    },
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#email",
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Email is required",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                emailConfirm: {
                    required: "Confirm Email is required",
                    email: "Please enter a valid confirm email address",
                    equalTo: "Confirm Email must match Email"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function() {

                return false;
            }
        });
    }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing your two missing bracket typos, there is nothing wrong with Validation plugin.  Enter an invalid email address and see the error message.

Your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/wZfHa/

The problem is apparently within your logic...

```
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: {  // only required if 'emailConfirm' is filled out
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#emailConfirm").is(":filled");
                }
            },
            email: true
        },
        emailConfirm: {
            required: {  // only required if 'email' is filled out
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#email").is(":filled");
                }
            },
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#email",
        }
    }
```

The first field is only `required` if the second field is filled out.  The second field is only `required` if the first field is filled out... so if neither field is filled out, then nothing is required and the form will submit because it's technically "valid".  If that's what you wanted, then it's working fine.